# How can I see the exact properties that are set with xset?

Tags: x11, xinput, xset

The two main utilities to configure and test X input devices are `xinput` and `xset`.

The main difference between the two (for what I understand) is that `xinput` allows a more fine-grained control over the (possibly device-dependent) properties.
On the other hand, sometimes the settings given via `xset` are a pretty good starting point.

What I would like to do is to start from the settings given by `xset` and apply some fine-tuning from there via `xinput`.

The problem is that it seems that the configurations obtained via `xset` are not registered by `xinput`, and the `xset` man page does not give the exact details of the settings it produces.

For example, say I want to change the speed of my touchpad.
I know from `xinput --list` that the relevant device id is 15, so that I can use `xinput --list-props 15` to list all the touchpad properties.
I could now go and change some property, say the constant deceleration (which in this case has ID 276) to the value 1.5, using `xinput --set-prop 15 276 1.5`.

However, `xset mouse 5 5` also gives a pretty good speed setting for me.
I want to understand what exact configurations are being configured with this command, but running `xinput --list-props 15` after `xset mouse 5 5` does not register any difference.
How can I get this information?

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer, but I figured out some details by looking at the source code.

I had a look at the source code of `xset` in the file `xset.c`, which comes from the package `x11-xserver-utils`. The code in the file downloaded on my system (Ubuntu 16.04) by `apt-get source x11-xserver-utils` is more or less the same as the code found [here](https://salsa.debian.org/xorg-team/app/x11-xserver-utils/blob/fed54c72d60f741fc7e90dfb420bde3274f85871/xset/xset.c#L450-475), so I will use the code on that page as reference.

What happens when the `mouse` option is given can be seen at L475-502 (EDIT: in the updated ref L450-475):

```
/*  Set pointer (mouse) settings:  Acceleration and Threshold. */
  else if (strcmp(arg, "m") == 0 || strcmp(arg, "mouse") == 0) {
    acc_num = SERVER_DEFAULT;             /* restore server defaults */
    acc_denom = SERVER_DEFAULT;
    threshold = SERVER_DEFAULT;
    if (i >= argc){
      set_mouse(dpy, acc_num, acc_denom, threshold);
      break;
    }
    arg = argv[i];
    if (strcmp(arg, "default") == 0) {
      i++;
    } 
    else if (*arg >= '0' && *arg <= '9') {
      acc_denom = 1;
      sscanf(arg, "%d/%d", &acc_num, &acc_denom);
      i++;
      if (i >= argc) {
       set_mouse(dpy, acc_num, acc_denom, threshold);
       break;
      }
      arg = argv[i];
      if (*arg >= '0' && *arg <= '9') {
       threshold = atoi(arg);  /* Set threshold as user specified.  */
       i++;
      }
    }
    set_mouse(dpy, acc_num, acc_denom, threshold);
  }
```

where `SERVER_DEFAULT` is set as `-1`.
This just reads the arguments and calls `set_mouse`.
Notably, if no additional arguments are given (command called as `xset mouse`) the defaults are `xset mouse -1/-1 -1`. Also, `acc_num` and `threshold` must be between 0 and 9, otherwise the default value `-1` is used, and the default value for `acc_denom` is 1.

The function `set_mouse` is again just a bunch of checks for illegal input values:

```
set_mouse(Display *dpy, int acc_num, int acc_denom, int threshold)
{
int do_accel = True, do_threshold = True;

if (acc_num == DONT_CHANGE)        /* what an incredible crock... */
  do_accel = False;
if (threshold == DONT_CHANGE)
  do_threshold = False;
if (acc_num < 0)                   /* shouldn't happen */
  acc_num = SERVER_DEFAULT;
if (acc_denom <= 0)                /* prevent divide by zero */
  acc_denom = SERVER_DEFAULT;
if (threshold < 0) threshold = SERVER_DEFAULT;
XChangePointerControl(dpy, do_accel, do_threshold, acc_num,
                    acc_denom, threshold);
return;
}
```

The ball is now passed to `XChangePointerControl`. This function is however not defined in this package. Some searching through the included dependencies brought me to the `libx11` package, containing the file `ChPntCont.c` (source code [here](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/39672434/)), which defines this function:

```
int
XChangePointerControl(
     register Display *dpy,
     Bool do_acc,
     Bool do_thresh,
     int acc_numerator,
     int acc_denominator,
     int threshold)

{
    register xChangePointerControlReq *req;

    LockDisplay(dpy);
    GetReq(ChangePointerControl, req);
    req->doAccel = do_acc;
    req->doThresh = do_thresh;
    req->accelNum = acc_numerator;
    req->accelDenum = acc_denominator;
    req->threshold = threshold;
    UnlockDisplay(dpy);
    SyncHandle();
    return 1;
}
```

I didn't really manage to understand much beyond this point. `GetReq` is defined by a macro in the file `Xlibint.h` in the `libx11` package and we get bounced around between several different functions.
At the end of the day we probably have enough information from the above functions though, in that the input values seem to be directly fed as new values for similarly named properties of the touchpad device.

The above at least tells us something about the default and accepted values of `xset`.

I didn't manage to figure out why the output of `xinput list-props` is not updated after the properties are changed with `xset` though.

Comment: Hi @gIS thanks for this. The code ref is broken; I found https://salsa.debian.org/xorg-team/app/x11-xserver-utils/blob/debian-unstable/xset/xset.c Not sure if it is right to drop in this href?

Comment: @Rob glad it helped. Thanks for the catch, I updated the link. It's probably a different version of the package, as the line numbers are different, but the code block is identical, so it should be fine (and I don't really remember the exact version of the library I was referring to here)